# Why Hive when HDFS already provide data storage?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have started learning Hadoop.I understood that HDFS provides distributed storage system and Mapreduce is for data processing.Now i ma reading Hadoop ecosystem.
From the definition of Hive, it is a data ware house built on hadoop for providing SQL like interface.

My question is when hadoop provides HDFS which is falut tolerant , distributed then why hive? Does hive replaces HDFS?.

Does hive provide only sql interface or storage also?

Answer (score 2):

Hive does not replace HDFS. Hive provides sql type interface to data that is stored in HDFS. Its basically used for querying and analysis of data that is stored. Hive in a sense actually eliminates a lot of boiler plate code, that you would have to write if you were using mapreduce. for example just think of how you are going to create  different types of joins(left, right, bucketed)  or group by clause or any other sql clause in mapreduce and you will get your answer (you lines of code will easily scale to 100's ). Hive provides them out-of-the-box. You dont need to write those lengthy programs in mapreduce. Hive already does that for you.

One thing to note is, Hive itself uses Mapreduce behind the scenes. So any group by, count, join is converted to mapreduce jobs only. You can change this though to Tez/Spark.

for your second question, hive does not provide any storage, it just uses a database (derby as default, MySQL would be a good choice if you want to use a different db) as a metastore just to store the metadata related to the tables, partitions, views, buckets etc.. (metadata is like location of tables, type of data stored in tables, partitions info of the tables, created date, modified date etc..) you create with hive.

Comment: Can hive process unstructured data?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in comment...

Hive can process structured (csv,txt etc) data & semi-structured(xml,json,parquet etc). It cannot process unstructured data like audio, video etc.

Note:  Semi structured data can be handled in DDLs and also through spark to be put into Hive.

I encourage you to learn what is external and managed tables in hive too.

Happy learning.